# ajax auto refresh div values other version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My case is different to other questions. I have a div with this code `<div id="ondiv"><?php ?></div>`

Inside that php are people who are online. When a user's login the div will refresh and be able to see the person who just logged in. I have tried the code from previous question like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#oldiv").load("chat.php");
}, 2000);
});
```

`but what it did is reload the page and what it display on my div was the whole page of the chat.php. What I want is just refresh the div's to display the user who just login inside php code.

Comment: try document.URL +  ' #thisdiv' inside the load $("#oldiv").load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');

Comment: If you're building a chat system I would strongly suggest you look in to using websockets over an AJAX polling pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to load method of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/load/

It takes the content of chat.php and place inside #oldiv.

You can change your chat.php or create a new file to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

.load() really only usable when the call only will result in HTML. If I were you I would do this with ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'chat.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#oldiv").html(data); // or ondiv, didn't get it
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a container(div) in `chat.php` which holds all the online users.

You can load only `fragment from the page` in your target element.

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded. Ref [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#oldiv").load("chat.php #container_which_holds_online_user");
  }, 2000);
});
```